# Rotation in spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I was trying a lazy way to derive rotation matrix, but then I have observed something funny -- there seem to be two kinds of rotations:

Suppose we rotate a book about its vertical axis perpendicular to its plane - the axis is *outside* of the $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, if we rotate an apple about any axis- the axis is always *inside* of the $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Another way to see it: For an ant on a book, we can fool it in two ways: one is to rotate the book about an axis perpendicular to the plane; another is to about any axis parallel the book. The Physics laws will be different in two cases, as the ant is in different sorts of non-inertial frames.

Hence, given a $\mathbb{R}^2$  (a subspace of a $\mathbb{R}^3$), there seems to be two kinds of rotations.

Now I wonder if we have these two kinds of rotations in our $\mathbb{R}^3$ space world - somehow rotate things "about the time axis"?

---

After a few searches on the Internet, I have came across something about hyperbolic rotation(that seems relevant to my question), but sadly, as I know little relativity, I can't understand it.

Comment: I'm confused by this question - I don't really understand what you mean by the "z-axis" of a book. Are you talking about the fact that a rotation about an axis perpendicular to the book's "plane" acts differently on it than a rotation about an axis parallel to its plane? That's just what happens if you rotate a non-rotationally symmetric body, it's a property of the book, not of the rotation. The second part about relativity and "rotations" along the time axis really has nothing to do with the first - being "hyperbolic" (=boosts) are properties of the rotations, not of the objects acted upon.

Comment: sorry for my bad english and example. I mean rotating the book about an axis perpendicular to the book's "plane". And  the axis is *outside* the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane (we can't do it without $\mathbb{R}^3$). While we can do another rotation to the book: along any axis parallel to the book, the axis in within the $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Note that if you rotate about an axis parallel to the book, the book does not move in a plane, i.e. it's actually *this* rotation you need $\mathbb{R}^3$ for, while the rotation about the perpendicular axis happens entirely in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and could be described as such without referring to an axis at all.

Comment: @ACuriousMind ha, I was just thinking actually we can't do the second rotation along an axis parallel to the book without $mathbb{R}^3$. But why the rotation about the perpendicular axis could be described as such without referring to an axis at all?

Comment: It is a common misconception that rotation happens around the axis. In fact, rotation happens in the plane while the existence of the axis is not guaranteed. There is no axis in 2D. There is one in 3D, but you still can see it as rotation in the plane rather than around the axis. In 4D, you can have two independent rotations at the same time in two orthogonal planes. In this case there would be no invariant axis of rotation in 4D.

Comment: When you say, "rotation around the time axis", you are under the same confusion. Rotation is not around the axis, but in the plane. For example, If your rotation is in the plane XY, then you can see any coordinate that is perpendicular to XY as the "axis of rotation". In this case you have two, Z and T. So rotation around any spatial axis is equivalent to rotation around the time axis. To avoid this confusion, it is better to speak of rotation in the plane. However, if your plane of rotation  includes the time coordinate, like XT, then rotation is hyperbolic meaning the Lorentz boost.

Comment: @safesphere thank you so much for the elaborating! it does make more sense to rotate in the plane than about an axis now.

Comment: All this lore of @safesphere can be derived by working with the linear transformations of cartesian coordinates that preserve distance and the origin (a representation of rotations). You can than derive, as a mathematical proof, that for an arbitrary linear transformations there will be always an cartesian coordinate that $D-2$ axis are preserved under that transformation, where $D$ is the dimension.

Comment: @Nogueira Your statement is correct only for a single rotation (such as for $\phi=0$ below), but I've already stated this above that, for example in 4D spacetime, a spatial rotation has two axes, spatial and temporal. However, in general, in 4D for example, one can have a dual rotation that preserves no axes. What specifically is your point? $$\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0&0\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0&0\\0&0&\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\0&0&\sin\phi&\cos\phi}$$

Comment: @safesphere you are right, I was too general. There are the possibility of compose $N$ commutative rotations in a space with $D=2N $ dimensions.